# user profile synchronization stuck on "synchronizing"

Tags: user-profile-service

Hi I am working on SharePoint 2010 and I have run user profile synchronization and it is stuck at "synchronizing" and not moving further.  It shows in central admin as "post-processing". I have attached image what i see when clicked on "synchronizing" in central admin. Also i have attached image of my central admin synchronization status.
Any suggestions?please help out.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: since when it is stuck( how much time)? Normally how much time it took to complete? any error in the Event log?

Comment: hi waqas I am getting ma-extension-error and the time it took for 7 hours.

Comment: could you please post the complete error details and how much time it took on average?

Comment: i have just posted an image what am currently finding in the synchronization manager.and also the error details. But i am not sure if this is related with synchronizing status and post-processing that is raising the issue of stuck in user profile sync.

Comment: http://www.chris-carmichael.com/sharepoint/?p=14

Comment: How is it today? stucked yet?

Comment: Its still same nothing is changing ...

Comment: we have adfs configured to the server and it is having some issues does that would be the reason for this.Not sure from me but just a quick thought ..can some one comment to this . Thanks

Comment: is it resolved?